# Cannot retrieve Facebook friends for user via graph api for non "me" user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the total friend count for an authorized user of our app:

```
GET /2.4/10107720201461/friends
```

where `10107720201461` is the user-id as referenced in [/user/friends Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/friends). I know that individual friends are only supposed to be shown if they have authorized by our app, and that is fine. I am only interested in the **summary** field for **total_count**. This works for the `me` user and works for admins of the app, but doesn't work for other users. Despite the fact that user `10107720201461` has authorized our app, and has explicitly granted the **user_friends** permission scope and our app is live to the public and has been reviewed by Facebook for extended permissions. I have verified the user's access token using Facebook's Access Token Debugger tool.

The response received is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported operation",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "Gi4F64t6eaM"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Access Token of the user with that ID, and it has to be valid. I assume you are using another Access Token. You should actually always use `/me`. If you want to get data from another user, either store his (Extended) Access Token or cache his data.

Edit: It MAY work with another User Token only **if both users are friends** - and both users have `user_friends` authorized.

Comment: Interesting. I had been using the access token of the logged in user. So I have to either let the client access another user's access token, or move all of these calls server side? That seems really unfortunate.

Comment: you definitely should not let a client access another users token...you should even activate appsecret_proof (see facebook docs) so you can only use tokens server side. but again, you could just cache the data whenever a user authorizes your app and comes back to it.

Comment: Totally agree. I would never implement the first proposal. It is just unfortunate that Facebook would impose this limitation when user 1's access token is scoped to my app, and user 2 has already granted my app the **user_friends** permission. The downside with caching is that I then need to either accept that the friend count will be stale or run some sort of background job to update it regularly. Thanks for the clarification though! I will update my implementation and accept your answer.

Comment: well, the friend count does not change THAT often ;) - i think updating it whenever the user visits your app should be good enough. no need for a background job or storing an extended token.

Comment: _“You have to use the Access Token of the user with that ID”_ – I think using another user’s access token works too, as long as both users are friends.

Comment: yeah, that could work too. i added it to my answer, should be easy to find out.